# forward slash '/' as file path separator in r

Tags: r

'/' could be used as file path separator in R.
like:

```
path <- 'c:/users/john'
setwd(path)
```

However, the following also works:

```
path <- 'c:////users///john'
setwd(path)
```

It seems that the number of slash does not affect the above statement.  I cannot find any rules about this.  Does anyone have any clue on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not `R` specific but depends on the operating system. At least for UNIX based platforms there is an official definition for this behaviour. In the [Single UNIX Specification/3.267 Pathname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_267) you can read the following:

> ... Multiple successive slash characters are considered to be the same as one slash, except for the case of exactly two leading slash characters. ...

Comment: @BowenSong if you are satisfied with the answer please accept it so the question is marked as answered.